# Primefaces Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'have found similar topics with this, but I am using Primefaces and I couldn't find a specific solution.

I am sharing the xhtml

SSCCE version:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectCondition"  value="#{ruleBean.selectedCondition}" style="width:300px">
            <p:ajax listener="#{ruleBean.onConditionSelected}" update="panelLinkerId" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yeni Koşul Ekle" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hava Durumu" itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Nem" itemValue="3" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sıcaklık" itemValue="4" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And here is the entire code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:b="http://books.org/jsf/taglib">

<h:body>    

<ui:composition template="/resources/templates/commonLayout.xhtml">

<!-- <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" /> -->
<!-- <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" target="head" /> -->

<ui:define name="head">
</ui:define>


<ui:define name="content">


<h:form id="form"> 

<p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true"/>
<h:outputText value="&#160;" />

<p:panel header="Ürün">
    <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="selectProduct"  value="#{ruleBean.selectedProduct}" style="width:300px">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bir Ürün Seçiniz" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{ruleBean.mappedProducts}" /> 
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="selectProductcard"  value="#{ruleBean.selectedProductcard}" style="width:300px">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bir Ürün Kartı Seçiniz" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{ruleBean.mappedProductcards}" /> 
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="selectRegion"  value="#{ruleBean.selectedRegion}" style="width:300px">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bir Bölge Seçiniz" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{ruleBean.mappedRegions}" /> 
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="selectPeriod"  value="#{ruleBean.selectedPeriod}" style="width:300px">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bir Dönem Seçiniz" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{ruleBean.mappedPeriods}" /> 
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
<p:panel header="Koşul" style="width:800px;text-align:center;">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="selectCondition"  value="#{ruleBean.selectedCondition}" style="width:300px">
        <p:ajax listener="#{ruleBean.onConditionSelected}" update="panelLinkerId" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yeni Koşul Ekle" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hava Durumu" itemValue="2" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Nem" itemValue="3" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sıcaklık" itemValue="4" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:panel>
<p:panel id="panelLinkerId" header="Bağlayıcı" style="width:800px;text-align:center;" widgetVar="panelLinker" visible="false">
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px;width:800px;text-align:center;" cellpadding="5" >
    <p:selectOneButton value="#{ruleBean.selectedTimeType}" >  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Geçmiş" itemValue="1" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Şimdi" itemValue="2" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Gelecek" itemValue="3" />
    </p:selectOneButton>
    <p:commandButton id="addLinker" value="Bağlayıcı Ekle" actionListener="#{ruleBean.showLinkerPopup}" update="growl" />
</h:panelGrid>  
</p:panel> 

<p:dialog header="Bağlayıcı Ekle" widgetVar="linkerPopup" resizable="false" id="linkerPopupDlg"  
            showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true"> 

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>


</h:form>  
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>

</html>
```

As you can see, when I select an item in the selectOneMenu with 'selectCondition' id, browser throws an this error: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined"**

Hence, this causes chain errors like commandbutton never calls its listener.

**ATTENTION:** The selectOneMenu calls onConditionSelected Java method when value changed, and the method calls 'panelLinker.show();' js code. When I remove this method and set panelLinker visibility to visible this error dissappears. So it makes this issue very weird.

I hope this isn't a Primefaces bug. I am waiting for your valuable approaches.

Cheers.

Comment: That can happen if you manually include jQuery JS files. Unfortunately, you did not show the XHTML markup in SSCCE flavor, so that cause couldn't be excluced by just glancing over the code. You just showed the entire template client without the master template. Please learn how to create SSCCE code snippets.

Comment: I showed the entire template because the error can be anywhere in the XHTML. (I witnessed many times) I editted the question, you can see above.

Comment: That's **exactly** the reason why you should learn how to create an SSCCE! An SSCCE is the *smallest possible but complete* code snippet which still exhibits the problem when one copy'n'paste'n'runs it without any additional non-obvious modifications (e.g. expect of autogenerated code) in a completely blank playground project with everything set to default (unless otherwise specified in the question). Your code is not in SSCCE flavor. It doesn't work when I copy'n'paste'n'run it in a blank playground project.

Comment: For example, how exactly did you think that `style="width:300px"` is relevant to the problem? Does your problem disappear when you remove that part? No? Then just keep it out to keep the code as short and relevant as possible (thus, in SSCCE flavor).

Comment: There are a number things that are just plain off about your code. The `<h:body/>` is outside the `<ui:composition/>` so that'll never work; The commented out include of primefaces js would also not function because (unless you explicitly specify so), comments are still parsed by the Facelets engine anyway

Comment: I always put <ui:composition/> inside <h:body/>, there are lots of xhtmls like this and works perfectly except this. I deleted all commented lines, it didn't work. When the page according to user action, sets panels visibility to true, this error throws. It forces me to make panels visible, and this is not user-friendly at all.